# What hidden volume encryption is available for Replicant, LineageOS and Android?

Tags: android, truecrypt

We are seeing more and more stories of people being coerced by US border officers into breaching their own security, by handing over passcodes to their phones. People need to be able to protect themselves from this misbehaviour.

https://www.theatlantic.com/technology/archive/2017/02/a-nasa-engineer-is-required-to-unlock-his-phone-at-the-border/516489/

http://www.dailyxtra.com/canada/news-and-ideas/news/us-customs-block-canadian-man-reading-scruff-profile-215531

One plausible approach to defending people whose First Amendment rights might be breached is to ensure that they can use hidden volumes like those provided by TrueCrypt and VeraCrypt on their phones. This would enable people to hand over a passcode that grants access only to a public, but apparently secret, version of their operating system or user accounts.

What facilities are available for Replicant, LineageOS and Android in this regard?